# Using Mean Value Theorem to prove $f$ is a contraction

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Using the Mean Value Theorem prove the following:
>
> Let $f:[a,b]\to[a,b]$ be differentiable. Then $f$ is a contraction if and only if there exists a $r\in(0,1)$ such that $|f'(x)|\leqslant r$, for all $x\in[a,b]$.

If I assume $|f'(x)|\leqslant r$.

Using the MVT then $f(b)-f(a)=f'(x)(b-a)$ for some $x\in (a,b)$

Then $|f(b)-f(a)|=|f'(x)(b-a)|\leqslant r|b-a| $then f is a contraction.

However the reverse it has been difficult to prove. Assuming $f$ is a contraction. $f(a)-f(b)\leqslant M(a-b)$ Now I need to prove $f'(x)=M$.

**Question**:

Could someone provide me a hint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a typo in the statement of the question? $f(x) \le r$ should be $|f'(x)| \le r$?

Comment: I agree that you have a typo starting out. But why do you say you need to prove $f'(x)=M$? Assuming $|f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|$ (with $M<1$), you should be able to deduce easily that $|f'(x)|\le M$ for all $x$.

Comment: For reverse assertion $|f'(x)|=\left|\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right|\leq k \: \text{where} \:k\in(0,1).$ This is because $f$ is given to be differentiable  so $f'$ exists and application of mean value theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$|f'(x)| = \left|\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}\right| = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(x+h) - f(x)|}{|(x+h) - x|} \le M.$$

Comment: Or just note that $f'(x) =\lim_{y \to x} \frac{| f(y) - f(x)|}{|y-x|}$ and all term are bounded by $M$, so the derivative, the limit of terms in $[0,M]$ lies in $[0,M]$ as well, so $|f'(x)| \le M$.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party, are you familiar with the mean value inequality please?

If $f \in C[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$, then

$$
\displaystyle \sup_{x \in (a, b)} |f'(x)| \geq |\frac{f(a) - f(b)}{a - b}| \\
$$

$$
\iff |f(a) - f(b)| \leq \sup_{x \in (a, b)} |f'(x)| \cdot |a - b|
$$

By assumption, we have $\displaystyle \sup_{x \in (a, b)} |f'(x)| \leq r$, with $r \in (0, 1)$, hence $f$ is a contraction.